# How to make a golf simulator program in processing?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, processing

I am making a golf simulation in my computer science class, and I can't seem to finalize the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

int [][] golf = new int[4][9];
  void setup()
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Golf Simulator" + '\n');
  int input = 0;
  do {
    String in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1. See the final results table" + '\n' + 
      "2. Enter the golf scores for Player 1 " + '\n' + "3. Enter the golf scores for Player 2" + 
      '\n' + "4. Enter the golf scores for Player 3" + '\n' + "5. Enter the golf scores for Player 4" +
      '\n' + "6. Results for holes" + '\n' + "7. Exit program", null);
    input = Integer.parseInt(in);  

    char c = in.charAt(0);

    switch(c) {
    case '1': 
      showgolf();
      break;

    case '2':
      for (int i = 0; i < golf.length; i++)
      {
        String inn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the golf scores for Player 1", null);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(inn);
        golf[i] = n;
      }
      break;

    case '3':
      for (int i = 0; i < golf.length; i++)
      {
        String inn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the golf scores for Player 2", null);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(inn);
        golf[i] = n;
      }
      break;

    case '4':
      for (int i = 0; i < golf.length; i++)
      {
        String inn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the golf scores for Player 3", null);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(inn);
        golf[i] = n;
      }
      break;

    case '5':
      for (int i = 0; i < golf.length; i++)
      {
        String inn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the golf scores for Player 4", null);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(inn);
        golf[i] = n;
      }
      break;

    case '6':
      for (int i = 0; i < golf.length; i++)
      {
        String inn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the hole number", null);
        int n = Interger.parseInt(inn);
         golf[i] = n;
      }
      break;

default:
    JOtionPane.showMessageDialog("Thank you for using Golf Simulator");   
    break;
}

}while(input != 7);
}

void showgin()
{
  String str = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < golf.length; i++)
  {
    str = str + win[i] + '\n';
  }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str);
}
```

As I mentioned, I am a beginner, so I have probably done countless mistakes in this. I am supposed to use a 2D array in order to have 4 different players with 9 holes. On this simulator, there need to be a pop-ups which show:

- the whole table
- the user can insert the scores for each player
- the user searches the hole number, and gives the result (eg Player 1 won or there is a tie in Hole 2)
- ability to exit program

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: That's way to much in one question.

Comment: could you put what happens ? what do you enter ?, what are you expecting ? what do you get ? put some traces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a 2-dim array `golf[4][9]`, `golf.length` will return `4`. This is because you basically have an array with length 4 of arrays with length 9. So `golf[0].length` will give you 9.
So your cases 2 - 5 should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < golf[0].length; i++) {
    String inn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the golf scores for Player 1", null);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(inn);
    golf[0][i] = n; // use 0 for player 1, 1 for player 2, ...
}
break;
```

`showgin` which I suppose should be called `showWin` must take a number for the hole.

```
void showWin(int hole){
```

here we have to do some logic to find out if two players are tied or one player won. I did this using a list of tied players.

```
int score = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> tied = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < golf.length; i++) {
    if(golf[i][hole] > score){ // new winnger
        score = golf[i][hole]; // adjust high score
        tied.clear(); // throw out every tied player
        tied.add(winner); // add the winner
    } else if (golf[i][hole] == score){ // we have a new tied player
        tied.add(i); // add him
    }
}
```

Now we can look at the list, and if there is more than one player in it, we have a tie, otherwise the single player won.

```
if(tied.size() <= 1){
    str += "Winner: " + winner + " with score: " + score;
} else {
    str += "Tied: ";
    for(int i : tied){ // add all tied player to the output
        str += i + " ";
    }
    str += "with score: " + score;
}
```

Comment: void showWin(int hole){ : it gives me an error first on the void and then on the int. What should I do?

Comment: Look at the error description and fix what it is saying is wrong. If you can't figure it out, post some more context, like the code around `void showWin(int hole){` and the error messages you get.